# My code is printing only false. What can be wrong?

Tags: java

I am getting output as `false`, everytime.

My aim is to print `true`, if `String t` is present in the same order in `String s`.

For example:

1. ```
   String s = "gagbgcgd";
   String t = "abcd";
   ```

   Expected output:

   > true
2. ```
   String s = "gagcgdgb";
   String t = "abcd";
   ```

   Expected output:

   > false

Here is the code.

```
public class StringCompare {
    public static boolean stringCompare(String t,String s) {
        if (t.length() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (t.charAt(0) == s.charAt(0)) {
            stringCompare(t.substring(1), s.substring(1));
        }
        else {
            stringCompare(t, s.substring(1));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "acaoadaianaga";
        String t = "coding";
        System.out.println(stringCompare(t,s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

When you recurse, you don't return the result of the recursion. Change

```
if(t.charAt(0)==s.charAt(0)){
    stringCompare(t.substring(1), s.substring(1));
}
else{
    stringCompare(t, s.substring(1));
}
```

to something like

```
if(t.charAt(0)==s.charAt(0)){
    return stringCompare(t.substring(1), s.substring(1));
}
else{
    return stringCompare(t, s.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Some of my other assignments had the same problem. But they are solved now.

Comment: @iVvaibhav If your problem is resolved, don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/243725).

Comment: @iVvaibhav As a note (since it looks like your switching between the accepted answers): you can only accept one answer. You have to decide which one.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem of your code is in the first execution of the recursion always return false no matter what the return value of remaining execution in the recursion.

You should change your code to something like:

```
if(t.charAt(0)==s.charAt(0)){
    return stringCompare(t.substring(1), s.substring(1));
}
else{
    return stringCompare(t,s.substring(1));
}
```

and remove the last `return false;` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the outer recursive calls you always returns false 
except 
`if(t.length()==0){return true;}`

look at Elliott Frisch's answer.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `.contains`. Example:

```
 boolean istrue = t.contains(s);
```

Comment: What I mean is: OP doesn't whant to check is `t` is in `s` as `t` currently is. OP what to check if the char in `t` are in `s`. `#contains` can't check that with `t.contains(s)`. So you could think about removing your incorrect answer, or you can improve it :).